# Return only entries with consecutive ascending or descending values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following values:

Customer | weekending | trailing_avg

Customer defines the customer entry, weekending is a weekly value, and trailing average is a utilization metric.

I would like to filter the results to show only the customers for whom the most recent (i.e. highest weekending) trailing_avg values are either ascending or descending consecutively.

Thus if customer A's most recent trailing averages were 7,6,5 they would be displayed, but if Customer B had averages of 7,8,6, they would not.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function just to assess the trend in the trailing_avg and having that build then simple query to take you wanna take.

Take a look at below code.
It is my happy improvisation but hope help you.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS f_trend//
CREATE FUNCTION f_trend (trend VARCHAR(100))

    RETURNS TEXT 

    BEGIN

    DECLARE cnt TEXT;

    SET @p = trend;
    SET @p_1n = 0;
    SET @p_2n = 0;
    SET @c = 0;
    SET @diff = 0;
    SET @d = 0;

    label1: LOOP

    SET @c = @c + 1;

    SET @p_1n = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@p,',',1);

    SET @p_2n = SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    REPLACE(@p,CONCAT(@p_1n,','),''),',',1);

    SET @p = REPLACE(@p,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@p,',',1),','),'');

    SET @diff = @p_2n - @p_1n;

    IF @diff > 0 AND ABS(@d) = (@c-1) THEN SET @d = @d + 1;
    ELSEIF @diff < 0 AND ABS(@d) = (@c-1) THEN  SET @d = @d - 1;
    ELSE SET @d = @d;
    END IF;

    IF @c >= LENGTH(trend) - LENGTH(REPLACE(trend, ',', '')) THEN
        LEAVE label1;
    END IF;

    ITERATE label1;

    END LOOP label1;

    IF abs(@d) = @c AND @d > 0 THEN 
        SET cnt=(SELECT 'ASC');
    ELSEIF abs(@d) = @c AND @d < 0 THEN
        SET cnt=(SELECT 'DESC');
    ELSE SET cnt=(SELECT 'N/A');
    END IF;

    RETURN cnt;

    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

And the query to retrieve what you want:

```
SELECT customer 
FROM info
WHERE weekending = (SELECT MAX(weekending) FROM info) 
AND f_trend(trainling_avg) IN ('ASC','DESC');
```

It is not the best option but all depends what you need it for and what is the scale.

Comment: That is not valid for Postgres.

Comment: Yep. It s for mysql only. Sorry, i did not notice postgresql tag.

Answer (score 0):

Query without range of date.

`WITH tmpt AS (
   select Customer, 
          weekending, 
          trailing_avg, 
          CASE WHEN trailing_avg + 1 = LEAD(trailing_avg, 1) OVER(ORDER BY Customer, weekending,trailing_avg) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flg,
          CASE WHEN trailing_avg + 1 = LAG(trailing_avg, 1) OVER(ORDER BY customer,weekending,trailing_avg) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flg1
   FROM test
), Customer AS (
   SELECT Customer, count(flg) AS flg, count(flg1) AS flg1 
   FROM tmpt 
   WHERE flg1 = 0 AND flg = 0 GROUP BY Customer
)
SELECT * FROM test WHERE Customer IN (SELECT Customer FROM Customer WHERE flg + flg1 = 2);`

I understand what was wrong.
Forgot to add PARTITION BY Customer

`// trailing_avg < if step metric random or trailing_avg + 1 if step metric only +/-1
-CASE WHEN trailing_avg + 1 = LEAD(trailing_avg, 1) OVER(ORDER BY Customer, weekending,trailing_avg) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flg,
-CASE WHEN trailing_avg + 1 = LAG(trailing_avg, 1) OVER(ORDER BY customer,weekending,trailing_avg) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flg1
+CASE WHEN trailing_avg < LEAD(trailing_avg, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY  weekending,trailing_avg) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flg,
+CASE WHEN trailing_avg < LAG(trailing_avg, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY weekending,trailing_avg) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flg1` 

Changed example:

`WITH tmpt AS (
   select Customer,
          weekending,
          trailing_avg,
          CASE WHEN trailing_avg < LEAD(trailing_avg, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY  weekending,trailing_avg) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flg,
          CASE WHEN trailing_avg < LAG(trailing_avg, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY weekending,trailing_avg) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flg1 
          FROM test
), Customer AS (
   SELECT Customer, count(flg) AS flg, count(flg1) AS flg1
   FROM tmpt
   WHERE flg1 = 0 AND flg = 0 GROUP BY Customer
)
SELECT * FROM test WHERE Customer IN (SELECT Customer FROM Customer WHERE flg + flg1 = 2);`